# Tool to save the track names and links of a SoundCloud account

Tags: gratis, backup, soundcloud

I'm looking for a tool to list/save/backup the (public) track names and their links of a given [SoundCloud](https://soundcloud.com/) account.

For example, at a minimum, given the following web address...

```
https://soundcloud.com/<USER_NAME>/sets/<SET_NAME>
```

...the tool should create a human readable file (*.txt* or .*xml* or *.json*, etc.) containing the list of **track names (artist and title)** and **SoundCloud links** of that set.

Even better if the tool could save more data, such as the list of *Followers* and *Following*, *Likes*, *Reposts*, etc.:

```
https://soundcloud.com/<USER_NAME>/followers
https://soundcloud.com/<USER_NAME>/following
https://soundcloud.com/<USER_NAME>/likes
https://soundcloud.com/<USER_NAME>/reposts
```

Note that I'm not interested in downloading the actual track.

The tool should be **gratis**, and I don't mind if it's a **web app**, a **Firefox extension**, a **desktop app** (running on Windows or Ubuntu) or an **Android app**, as long as it does what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [SoundCloud API](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide), I was able to create a simple script that should do almost everything you want and meets your requirements. It is able to collect information about:

- User ID
- User's Tracks
- User's Followers
- User's Following
- User's Favorites

The information is presented in JSON format, you can use any [JSON Viewer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/18839/133) you want, even this [online JSON viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/).

I also set up a repo and a domain for this project. If you need any other features, let me know in a comment:)

## [SoundCloud-Profile-Backup](https://soundcloud.onlineth.com/) ([open source](https://github.com/onlineth/SoundCloud-Profile-Backup))

[image: Soundcloud Profile Backup UI]

Comment: Thank you, +1 for the effort and solution proposed. Unfortunately, often the backup is not complete since the result for each resource seems to be limited to 50 items. For example, for the user _keithcarnal_, not all 96 Following are returned. I've used the [Online JSON Viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/).

Comment: @mguassa Hmm, that's odd - I would figure that the api would be able to retrieve everything but I'll see if I can fix this in a few hours

Comment: I had a look at the code on GitHub, but I'm not familiar with PHP. A couple of questions: about the `client_id`, is it the one you got by registering your web app on [SoundCloud apps](http://soundcloud.com/you/apps)? What's _secure.php_? I don't see the source code.

Comment: @mguassa I did register the app and the credentials are stored in secure.php. I have the file on the server and the git ignore so it won't be viewable to the public - I'll be at a computer in a few hours (typing from my phone) and I'll see what I can do

Comment: @mguassa Alright, I fixed a few issues including the one you mentioned, please tell me if it works for you or if you encounter anymore